# SQL MAX() Function return wrong tuple/result

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I make a Student assigment system in php/mysql. here table structure.

```
Student ------StudentAssignment -------Assignment -----attempt

StudentAssignment - stuID, assID, attID
attempts - attID, marks, assDate
```

student can do 3 attempts for one assignment.
I use following SQL statement to get MAX marks with its attDate.

```
SELECT a.title, MAX(att.marks), a.totalmarks, att.attDate 
FROM attempts att, studentassignment sa, assignment a 
WHERE sa.attID=att.attID AND sa.assID=a.ass_ID AND sa.assID=:assID AND sa.stuID=:stuID
```

but It return Max Mark with wrong attDate. attDate that return is first row's date of above sql statement.

[Result set without using MAX Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxnS5.jpg)

[Using MAX function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHGbX.jpg)

Comment: aggregate columns all by themselves are fine without a `group by`

Comment: Try using a join condition and a group by a,title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have numerous issues with your query:

- Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Never mix aggregation functions and unaggregated columns *unless* the unaggregated columns are in a `GROUP BY`.

For your purposes, you can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`, rather than `MAX()`:

```
SELECT a.title, att.marks, a.totalmarks, att.attDate 
FROM attempts att JOIN
     studentassignment sa
     ON sa.attID=att.attID JOIN
     assignment a 
     ON sa.assID=a.ass_ID
WHERE sa.assID = :assID AND sa.stuID = :stuID 
ORDER BY att.marks DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Remember, `MAX()` is a function that returns only the maximum value for a column.  It has no effect on the other values returned by the query.